# Create object from another object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like :

```
cols : [Object { name="firstname", type="string"}, Object { name="lastname", type="string"}, Object { name="valid", type="checkbox"} ....]
```

I need to create, from this object, and object like :

```
[
  {
    data: 'firstname'
  },
  {
    data: 'lastname'
  },
  {
    data: 'valid',
    type: checkbox
  }
]
```

The only rule is, if in the first object there is type="string", you just have to ignore it (check my second object). And of course it's just an example, so I need some automatic thing.

I'm trying to work in this function :

```
var headers = data.cols.map(function (el, index) {    
    return el.name;
});
```

Here I can retrieve my element `el.name` and `el.type`. But I don't know how can I create this specific object ? I tried with `splice`, `push`... but for create multiple lines etc.. I have no idea.

Comment: Sorry, i'm working with symfony, but in this question it's not usefull you are right

Comment: That's not a valid object ?

Comment: JSON is a **data-format**, like XML or CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` function itself, but you need to create a new object and add all the fields based on the condition, like this

```js
var data = [{
    name: 'firstname',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'lastname',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'valid',
    type: 'checkbox'
}];

var result = data.map(function (currentObject) {

    var object = {
        // Create an object with `name` property
        data: currentObject.name
    };

    if (currentObject.type !== 'string') {
        // create `type` property in the `object`, only if type is not `string`
        object.type = currentObject.type;
    }

    return object;
});

console.log(result);

[ { data: 'firstname' },
  { data: 'lastname' },
  { data: 'valid', type: 'checkbox' } ]
```

Comment: It should be `data: currentObject.name`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Note that the initial array is invalid, and the objects within has no `data` properties, but in theory I suppose this could work, or something ?

Comment: @adeneo He can apply this idea, but I had to construct the object on my own. I included that also now :-)

Answer (score 0):

use map function and return based on condition

```
var result = data.cols.map(function (d, i) {
    if (d.type == "string") 
        return { data: d.name } 
    else 
        return { data: d.name, type: d.type }
});
```